# UIBarButtonItem unclickable

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem

I try to create a view without using xib file.
Unfortunately, I have problems early in my development.

I just want to add a navigationBar and an OK button in it.
Everything seems to be ok but in the simulator when I click on the button, nothing happens.
The selector is not called and it seems also that the button is not reached (no change of the aspect).

If you can have a look to my code, it would help.

```
-(void)loadView {
    //Set view background
    UIImageView * backView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:MM_BACKGROUND]] autorelease];
    [self setView:backView];

    //Set navigationBar
    UINavigationBar* navBar = [[[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
    navBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
    navBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    navBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

    UINavigationItem* navBarTitle = [[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"My title"] autorelease];    
    UIBarButtonItem* backButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered  target:self action:@selector(onTouchBackButton)] autorelease];
    navBarTitle.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
    [navBar pushNavigationItem:navBarTitle animated:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:navBar];

}
```

Thanks

Maxime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view controller's *view* is an *UIImageView*. *UIImageView's* user interaction is disabled by default. So it disables the user interaction of all its subviews too (that's why the button doesn't respond to touches). You have to explicitly set,

```
backView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Thank you, it fixed my problem. I could look for the solution a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the code for `onTouchBackButton` selector ?

But just a wild guess, maybe you should change your code to `...action:@selector(onTouchBackButton:)] autorelease];`

notice the presence of **:** this is needed as your `IBAction` takes an arg `(id) sender`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, after I applied the fix from @EmptyStack, my app crashed because of the missing ":"

Answer (score 0):

Maxime Capelle,

Try this code,

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    UIButton* backgbtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [backgbtn setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backgbtn setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
    [backgbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem* backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backgbtn];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:backBarButtonItem];
    [backBarButtonItem release];
    [backgbtn release];
```

Comment: Maxime Capelle,write button action event -(IBAction)goBack{}